# GDB memory examination output off by 8 bytes compared to actual memory content

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gdb, g++4.8

I'm experiencing a weird inconsistency between the memory dump output I get from GDB's *x* command when dumping memory several KB into a complex C++ object. At the GDB prompt I get:

```
(gdb) x/32b 0x7FFFCD82B000
0x7fffcd82b000: 0xf8    0x23    0xae    0xf2    0xff    0x7f    0x00    0x00
0x7fffcd82b008: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffcd82b010: 0xff    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffcd82b018: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
```

And this corresponds to abnormal values of object members, e.g. bools with values other than 0 or 1.
However, When dumping the content of this memory area from /proc/*pid*/mem I get 0 in the first 8 bytes and then the same memory content as above (the left column is the memory offset in decimal):

```
 0  0
 1  0
 2  0
 3  0
 4  0
 5  0
 6  0
 7  0
 8 f8
 9 23
10 ae
11 f2
12 ff
13 7f
14  0
15  0
16  0
17  0
18  0
19  0
20  0
21  0
22  0
23  0
24 30
25 21
26 4c
27 f4
28 ff
29 7f
30  0
31  0
```

I'm using GDB 7.7.1 on Linux 3.13 (Ubuntu 14.04). My code is C++ 11 and I compile using g++ 4.8.2 that came with the system.

The Python script I used to dump the content of /proc/.../mem shown above:

```
fp = open('/proc/24821/mem', 'r')
fp.seek(0x7fffed82b000)
r = fp.read(32)
for n, c in enumerate(r): print '%2d' % n, '%2x' % ord(c)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The rest of content is not the same. Look at byte starting from 24. Also 0x7fffed82b000 (in python) != 0x7FFFCD82B000 (in GBD)

Comment: My guess is that you are looking at data that is on the top of the stack, after taking a reference of a local variable and then returning from the function. The fact that the same 8 bytes occur in that and a simillar address is then stored at bytes 24-31 indicated that you are looking at a stackframe, either with references to other data on the stack or the top of the stack with frame-pointers.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the difference in the addresses. Guess I took the examples from two different runs of my executable, but the issue is real, please see my answer below.
Also note, that the object is allocated on the heap via *new* and not on the stack

Answer (score -1):

Found what was causing this weird behavior: The use of *-fsanitize=address* option to g++. I didn't see any GDB bug report about this, so guess it's my responsibility here :-)
Thanks to whoever gave my question consideration!

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain *anything*, and is very likely wrong.